# Implementation in js to find if N can be written as X ^Y , N<100

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

From past year ,i have been mainly working on Js, and so have started implementing Algo Questions in js .can it be implemented in a better way.

```
/**
* Implementaion to find if a number can be expressed as x^y
* x is assumed to be >=0 
*/

var canBeExpressedAsXraisedToY = function (n) {
if (n == 0 && n == 1) {
    console.log("Supplied 0 or 1");
    return true;
}
else if (n > 1) {
    var x = 2, prod = 1,y = 1;
    while (prod < n) {

        while (prod < n ) {

            prod = Math.pow(x,y);
            console.log('prod:',prod,'y:', y ,'x:',x)
            if (prod == n) {
                console.log('it can be expressed as x:', x, 'in terms of:', y);
                return true;
                break;
            }
          y++;
        }
        x++;
    }

    console.log("the number cannot be expressed as x ^ y ");
    return false;
}
else { // to handle negative cases .
    console.log('the number given is not supported ');
    return false;
}
}

console.log(canBeExpressedAsXraisedToY(4));
console.log(canBeExpressedAsXraisedToY(67));
console.log(canBeExpressedAsXraisedToY(64));
```

Comment: It would much more efficient (and more interesting) to implement an [nth root algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm).
The time complexity of this approach should be about \$\mathcal{O}(log(n)^2)\$.
Alternatively, you can use the `math.nthRoot` function of math.js. This would need to be called \$\mathcal{O}(log(n))\$ times.
We would love to review your code once you have a (working) example. Preferably one you've worked on first, until it's as good as you can get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is wrong. `canBeExpressedAsXraisedToY(81)` returns `false`.

Of course any *n* can have a trivial solution *x*=*n* and *y*=1.  I assume you want to require *y*>1. But you didn't state that anywhere, and in fact initialize `y=1` in your code.

Initializing `prod=1` is sloppy programming. You should structure the loops to compute `prod` before testing it.

That is pretty much a brute-force exhaustive search. For large *n*, a much better strategy would be to analyze the prime factors of *n* instead.

Comment: have added another answer in the comments, with another logic, which should be O(n) in the worst case.